# How to get all classes in particular dll, browse through OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I have been trying to write a code for getting all classes in particular dll runtime. Dll must be selected by user using OpenFileDialog. After selection it list all the classes in selected dll. I have tried following code with no success. Also google it but not find any concrete solution.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           Type t = openFileDialog1.OpenFile().GetType();
        }           
    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx? There is snippet at the bottom of a page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(openFileDialog1.FileName);

foreach (var type in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
{
   Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
}
```

It loads the assembly with the given name, gets all Types and lists them.